# Android - Cannot receive C2DM Registration Intent

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am attempting to register my device with C2DM and am having major issues. I have followed several tutorials, all of which are very similar. I believe the issue has to do with the registration intent that it sends to the C2DM server. Does anyone have any suggestions. The following is the relevant code:

Manifest: **The permissions** (outside my application tag):

```
<!-- Used for C2DM -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.companyname.parade.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

This is the Intent registration (inside my application tag):

```
<receiver
    android:name=".C2DMReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <!-- Receive the actual message -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

        <category android:name="com.companyname.parade" />
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- Receive the registration id -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.companyname.parade" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The following is what I call to register my device to the C2DM server (it starts the service that contacts the C2DM servers that is suppose to send back a registration Intent with my registartionID in it). It is located in a file called **C2DMessaging**:

```
public static void register(Context context) {
    Intent registrationIntent = new Intent(REQUEST_REGISTRATION_INTENT);
    registrationIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_APPLICATION_PENDING_INTENT,
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    registrationIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SENDER, SENDER_ID);
    ComponentName name = context.startService(registrationIntent);
    if(name == null){
        // FAIL!
        Log.d(TAG, "FAIL");
    }else{
        // SUCCESS
        Log.d(TAG, "Success");
    }
}
```

The ComponentName info is the following:

```
com.google.android.gsf/com.google.android.gsf.gtalkservice.PushMessagingRegistrar
```

There is no logcat output. My receiver (named **C2DMReceiver**) is the following:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (C2DMessaging.INTENT_REGISTRATION_CALLBACK.equals(action)) {
        // Registration Intent
        Log.w(TAG, "Registration Receiver called");
        handleRegistration(context, intent);
    } else if (action.equals(C2DMessaging.INTENT_RECEIVED_MESSAGE_CALLBACK)) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Message Receiver called");
        handleMessage(context, intent);
    } else if (action.equals(C2DMessaging.INTENT_C2DM_RETRY)) {
        C2DMessaging.register(context);
    }
}
```

This does not get called at all.

**Edit**: This whole thing was a stupid mistake on my part. I simply forgot a step somehow in the tutorials I read. I need to add this to my permissions:

```
<permission android:name="com.companyname.parade.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Thanks to MisterSquonk for the response.

Comment: "My receiver (named C2dmReceiver)" - Is that just a typo? It should be C2DMReceiver (with capitals). I assume it was a typo but thought I'd check.

Comment: It was, in fact, just a typo. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: OK, just thought I'd check. The only thing I can see which you haven't shown is having an entry like this...`<permission android:name="com.companyname.parade.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
`. Do you have that set in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: That was it. Thanks. If you want to answer it, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Glad it helped. I've added an answer and padded it out slightly in case it's of any help to others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Google docs for C2DM for [Creating the Manifest](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html#manifest), the manifest needs a `<permission>` entry to complement the `<uses-permission>` entry for `C2D_MESSAGE`.

Something like this...

```
<permission android:name="com.companyname.parade.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial worked for me in getting me up to speed:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

I'm not sure why you have two intent filters. I only needed one - com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION (see tutorial above for a complete example manifest)

I'd check your manifest is correctly referencing the receiver class - perhaps try a fully-qualified reference to the class. I had an issue at one point where I moved receiver class in my project structure and all messages stopped.

I'd also check that the C2DM account is set up right, and with the right package name.

I'd also try it on another device, as in my experience some Android devices fall off C2DM and just don't receive messages for a period of time. I find sometimes flicking to airplane mode and back sorts it out, but I found testing on several devices essential to rule out problems with a specific device.